# ruby execute_script for custom function leads to no results

Tags: javascript, ruby, rspec, automation, ui-automation

I have custom JS function about some of page performance details
Doing automation via ruby-rspec-capybara
Having next code:

```
    visit page
    execute_async_script("function getPagePerformance(){if (window.performance && window.performance.timing) {
    let timing = window.performance.timing;
    let timing_obj = {};
    /*timing*/
    timing_obj.pageLoadingTime = timing.loadEventEnd - timing.navigationStart;
    timing_obj.dnsHandshake = timing.domainLookupEnd - timing.domainLookupStart;
    timing_obj.tcpConnect = timing.connectEnd - timing.connectStart;
    timing_obj.timeToReachServer = timing.responseStart - timing.requestStart;
    timing_obj.serverResponseTime = timing.responseEnd - timing.responseStart;
    timing_obj.totalNetworkLatency = timing.responseEnd - timing.fetchStart;
    timing_obj.domInteractive = performance.timing.domInteractive - performance.timing.navigationStart;return timing_obj;}}
getPagePerformance()")
```

I've tried it with all methods that ruby actually has:

```
execute_async_script
execute_script
evaluate_script
```

And there is no results in console
But they are if im doing it manually
In additional i've tried to set `alerts` or `console.log` inside function just to check if all lines are executed at all - all alerts are being displayed during test running

I've added waiting to make sure that page is loaded (just to exclude questions about this case)

my question is about why this function doesn't return values when test is run

Comment: what happens when you do `evaluate_script`? Any errors anywhere?

Comment: check if the standard output and standard error are redirected

Comment: "And there is no results in console" - I'm not seeing any code that writes to console.

Comment: Actually there was nothing in console, no errors - nothing. Answer below helped

Answer (score 0):

The call doesn't return anything because your script doesn't return anything.

Here's an example:

```ruby
timing = execute_script(%{
  var t = window.performance.timing;
  return {
    pageLoadingTime: t.loadEventEnd - t.navigationStart,
    dnsHandshake: t.domainLookupEnd - t.domainLookupStart,
    tcpConnect: t.connectEnd - t.connectStart,
    timeToReachServer: t.responseStart - t.requestStart,
    serverResponseTime: t.responseEnd - t.responseStart,
    totalNetworkLatency: t.responseEnd - t.fetchStart,
    domInteractive: t.domInteractive - t.navigationStart
  };
})
```

Comment: Yep, thanks a lot. it helped and it works if use without wrapping in function:    'if (window.performance && window.performance.timing) {
    let timing = window.performance.timing;
    let timing_obj = {};
 ...

 return timing_obj;
}'